# Interpretation of Anderson–Darling test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, goodness-of-fit

Assume that I am using Anderson–Darling test to evaluate whether a given sample of data is drawn from a normal distribution with some mean and standard deviation.

If you accept the null hypothesis in a the Anderson-Darling test with a p-value of 1.000, it means that you have failed to find evidence to reject the assumption that your data follows the specified distribution (e.g., the normal distribution).

Does this automatically imply that the sample mean and sample standard deviation are statistically significant?